# Xamarin Forms app unhandled exception debugging on Visual Studio

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-debugging

This is a general question, I am not posting any code as the problem is not in the code (but you can download the entire project her in case you find it useful: [native authentication flow in a Xamarin.Forms application](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/WebServices/OAuthNativeFlow/). If I am breaking some community rule please forgive me, if you can help thanks for I could not find an answer elsewhere.

Visual Studio 2015. Xamarin Forms cross platform PCL application.
The code builds and runs just fine on both VS android emulator and when deployed on a android 6.0 Samsung 815T device. Same code breaks with unhandled exception when deployed on android 7.0 Samsung SM-A510F device. Again this is NOT the problem but the only hint I get is this:

[image]

I am used to debug web application where unhandled exceptions are relatively rare and new to mobile development. Since I started studying Xamarin development I am systematically facing with this kind of unhandled exception.
Please note I can debug the application and hit breakpoints but that does not help a lot when the only information I get from the debugger is always "unhandled application". I guess I am missing the big point here so any hint
would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you get this exception window, please click the Continue button. Visual Studio stops debugging, you'll see the **stack trace in the Output Debug window**. You might have to scroll up a little. **Search for Unhandled Exception**.

And you also could go to **Help > Xamarin > Open Logs** in Visual Studio. A folder will open and the exceptions you're looking for are in those files.

Comment: Thanks Wendy, just what I was looking for. Unfortunately the exception doesn't help me understand why only one testing device out three causes this exception. I already knew it had to do with some json object contained in Xamarin.Auth... that,  I suppose, is why I can't manage to handle it. I will pose a more detailed question on some Xamarin's gurus forum. I've marked your answer as accepted.