# How debug unexplained exceptions VS 2019 Windows Xamarin Forms?

Tags: exception, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019, stack-trace

I'm new to Xamarin. I have a Xamarin Forms app that I am in the early stages of debugging. The code sometimes throws exceptions -- entirely my coding faults, no doubt. (I doubt that my specific code is relevant, so I am not posting.) How the heck does one locate the failing line of code? I see lots of threads on SO and MSDN with the same question but the answers must be for some other version of VS because I do not see the options they refer to. On the exception the Call Stack window displays only [External Code], even after I hit Continue as some have suggested. The Output window indeed tells me that an exception has been thrown but no clue as to the offending line of code -- at least no clue that I am getting. (It tells me NullReferenceException but not the module, variable, method name or line.)

I have been debugging these with guesswork, random breakpoints, and stepping through code until I get the exception. There must be a better way!

Comment: Here is one of the related threads where "hit continue and look at the Call Stack" seems to the the answer, but it does not work for me in VS 2019 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46266980/xamarin-forms-app-unhandled-exception-debugging-on-visual-studio?rq=1

Comment: I have been working in C++ for the past ten years, so I have a real tendency to code MyClass Foo; In C++ that gives you an instance of Foo; in C# that gives you a NullReferenceException waiting to happen. So I tend to run into them more than I should.

Comment: So have you found the problem?

Comment: I find every problem, But it is a matter of "guesswork, random breakpoints, and stepping through code," as I say in the post. I am looking for a systematic way of finding the problems. Is there a way to make VS pinpoint the offending statement (as, just as an example, VS 2010 does with C++).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently fixed in VS 2019 16.9.3. I just installed the update. As luck would have it, I soon got a null reference exception and it took me right to the line of C# at fault!